# Automate SSH and screen commands

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, automation, gnu-screen

I have a PHP script with a web interface which is used to provide input into a process which I am automating. In this process, I am attempting to include using SSH and screen to run some commands (all sent through PHP's exec).

I am currently using the following which is writing *echo sent from script* to the screen, but isn't executing it. I've tried adding the -ne option to echo and adding \n or ^M to the end. I've also tried changing around the types of quotes I'm using, but I'm having trouble getting the code to execute (sending enter).

```
ssh -t -t myUser@myDomain.com 'screen -r -d -S -X myScreen stuff "echo -ne sent from script"' 2>&1
```

How do I go about getting that code to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took much longer to figure out than I would like to admit. They key was adding a $ before the command sent to *stuff* and then using a \n to send the enter press.

I added an extra screen -list; to demonstrate how to send multiple commands before entering the screen. I also added an extra echo to demonstrate how to send multiple commands to the screen.

```
ssh -t -t myUser@myDomain.com "screen -list; screen -r -d -X -S myScreen stuff $'echo here; echo here\n'" 2>&1
```